# how to check ng-if after change event

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular 6 in my project.

I have a div element having *ng-if="edited" as below

```
<div *ngIf="edited">
    {{langText}}
</div>
```

on first load edited will be false and it won't be visible. But, I have a chance event like below,

```
<select (change)="getSelectedLang(i,$event.target.value)">
                <option value="0">Language</option>{{languages[0].Lang}}
                <option *ngFor="let selecLanguage of languages[0].Lang" value={{selecLanguage}}>
                    {{selecLanguage}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

Once I select any language from the drop-down, it will call a function where I have a web service API bound and getting the following result in JSON and I am making edited = true.

```
getSelectedLang(id,langName){
        this.edited = true;
        this.custService.getSelectedLanguageData(id,langName).subscribe((data:  Array<object>) => {
        this.langtext = data;
        this.langtext = JSON.stringify(this.langtext.comicPageTextLites);
        console.log(this.langtext);
        this.langtext = JSON.parse(this.langtext);
        console.log( "=====this.langtext=====" );
        console.log( this.langtext );
            $(".show_me").toggle();
            $(".show_me").show();
        });
    }

[{"pageNo":1,"text":"हैलो नासीर, आप कैसे हैं","x":"679","y":"689"},{"pageNo":2,"text":"मैं अच्छा हूँ","x":"568","y":"890"}]
```

Now, I need to show the div *ngIf="edited" in the UI. But, it's not displaying.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this. Every time I change the language from the drop down the result will change and I should show the data in UI.

Comment: As soon as you get a data from API call, you can toggle value of `edited` to `true` like `this.edited  = true`

Comment: I am doing that .it will call a function where I have a web service API banded and getting the following result in JSON and I am making edited = true. but no luck.

Comment: can you provide the code where you do  "this.edited = true;"  in the callback of your api ?

Comment: yeah sure .. will update in question.

Comment: probably, the `div` is there in UI because the `edited` you made true, but maybe the value of `langText` is empty and yhat is why nothing is there visible in UI. you can inspect and check the div exists in DOM by DOM inspecttor

Comment: @xrobert35 updated my question as you requested

Comment: You're setting `langtext` but binding to `langText`, so you need to change the template to `{{langtext}}` (or change the code to `langText` if you prefer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem is not about the "edited" variable, the *ngIf must work.

The name of the langtext variable if badly write in the html. You use langtext in the component en write "langText" in the html.